# VB.NET Import Excel table into DataGridView without external downloads

Tags: excel, vb.net, import, datagridview, connection

I know this question has been asked several times, but in my case the situation is a bit different since I cannot download anything as I develop on my company's machine and any download or installation is strictly forbidden.

I tried to import through any of the connection strings I always used with success in VBA: ACE, JET but the error is always

'**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:** 'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'

As stated above I also can not download external packages as Nuget or the ones which include the 'OledbConnection' methods.

Does anyone know how can I import excel tables into datagridview without external downloads?
Since I'm a beginner I'd appreciate any detailed answer.

**Edit:**

My pc is a 64bit and my app runs both 32 and 64bit.
Below the drivers for the 64bit part that are installed.

[image]

not having any of ACE DB in my list (I have it on the 32bit side) I'm not able to match them.

I've read in other topics that the suggested method involves the 'OleDbConnection' which i read is not part of the .NET environment but it can be get downloading the nuget package.
The code I use is the one below

```
Public Sub ImportWorksheet(WorkbookAddress As String, WorksheetName As String)
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim comm As ADODB.Command
    Dim path As String
    Dim sSQL As String


    conn = New ADODB.Connection
    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    comm = New ADODB.Command
    conn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & WorkbookAddress & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2""")

    With comm
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" + WorksheetName + "$]"
        .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        rs.Open(sSQL, conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic)
    End With
    rs = Nothing
    conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use Jet then you need to ensure that your app runs in a 32-bit process. If you use ACE, you need to ensure that the bigness of your app matches the edition of ACE you have installed. If you can't fix what you have with the previous advice, please post the relevant code, including your connection string. Note that `OleDb` is a standard part of .NET but you have said that you can't use it. Was that a mistake?

Comment: I added further details

Comment: As I said in my post i can't download anything. I am seeking for a solution with something installed by default in Visual Studio or in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a DataTable with the contents of the worksheet.

```
Public Function GetWorksheetData(fileName As String, worksheetName As String) As DataTable
    Dim connectionString As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={fileName};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"
    Dim query As String = $"SELECT * FROM [{worksheetName}$]"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection)
            Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
            adapter.Fill(dataTable)
            connection.Close()
            Return dataTable
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

OleDbConnection and OleDbDataAdapter are part of .Net Framework so do not require any additional libraries.